# Elastic search filter aggregation implementation with java

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

How should I implement it in java springboot using querybuilder?

```
GET logs/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs" : {
    "messages" : {
      "filters" : {
        "filters" : {
          "errors" :   { "match" : { "body" : "error"   }},
          "warnings" : { "match" : { "body" : "warning" }}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What did you try? Have you ever seen this documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html